# Create View with rank column in limited amount of data

Tags: mysql

So I have an MySQL table structured like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `spenttime` {
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `serverid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `day` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `dbid_sid_day` (`userid`,`serverid`,`day`)
}
```

Where I'm storing time spent on my game servers every day for each registered player. `time` is the amount of time spent, in seconds, `day` is an unix timestamp of each day (beginning of the day). I want to create an View on my database that will show for each user time spent on server every week, but with an column displaying rank of that time, independent for each server on each week. For example data (for clarify i will use date format Y-M-D instead of unix timestamp for `day` column on this example):

```
INSERT INTO `spenttime` (`userid`, `serverid`, `time`, `day`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 200, '2013-04-01'),
    (1, 1, 150, '2013-04-02'),
    (2, 1, 100, '2013-04-02'),
    (3, 1, 500, '2013-04-04'),
    (2, 2, 400, '2013-04-04'),
    (1, 1, 300, '2013-04-08'),
    (3, 1, 200, '2013-04-08');
```

For that data in viev named `spenttime_week` should appear:

```
+--------+----------+--------+------------+------+
| userid | serverid |  time  |  yearweek  | rank |
+--------+----------+--------+------------+------+
|     1  |       1  |   350  | '2013-W14' |   2  |
|     2  |       1  |   100  | '2013-W14' |   3  |
|     3  |       1  |   500  | '2013-W14' |   1  |
|     2  |       2  |   400  | '2013-W14' |   1  |
|     1  |       1  |   300  | '2013-W15' |   1  |
|     3  |       1  |   200  | '2013-W15' |   2  |
+--------+----------+--------+------------+------+
```

I know how to generate view wihout rank, i have only troubles with rank column...
How can I make that happen?

//edit
Additionaly, this column MUST appear in viev, I cannot generate It in select from that view, because app where I will use it don't allow that...

Comment: Can you share the sample output you wish to have

Comment: I replaced "incorrect" insert statement for spenttime_week by an table view. It should now clearly show what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create a first VIEW that sums the spent time for every user on the same week:

```
CREATE VIEW total_spent_time AS
SELECT userid,
       serverid,
       sum(time) AS total_time,
       yearweek(day, 3) as week
FROM spenttime
GROUP BY userid, serverid, week;
```

then you can create your view as this:

```
CREATE VIEW spenttime_week AS
 SELECT
  s1.userid,
  s1.serverid,
  s1.total_time,
  s1.week,
  count(s2.total_time)+1 AS rank
FROM
  total_spent_time s1 LEFT JOIN total_spent_time s2
  ON s1.serverid=s2.serverid
     AND s1.userid!=s2.userid
     AND s1.week = s2.week
     AND s1.total_time<=s2.total_time
GROUP BY  
  s1.userid,
  s1.serverid,
  s1.total_time,
  s1.week
ORDER BY
  s1.week, s1.serverid, s1.userid
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12165/1).

Comment: It works like a charm, but there is one thing that must be changed: `s1.total_time<=s2.total_time` will cause that if 2 players have exactly same time spend on server, and it is higher result on week, both of them will have rank 2 instead of 1. Making it `s1.total_time<s2.total_time` solves the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways you could get the yearweek column, a quick lazy solution to that for clarity (because I doubt you're struggling with that). But here's how you can get the rank. 
Use a self join to get dataset including rows with higher time value than current row, then count the rows with higher value:

This is much easier in MSSQL, which is where I live 99% of the time, and where you can just use the RANK() function. I hadn't realised until today there wasn't an equivalent in mysql. Fun to work out how to get the same result without MS's helping hand.

Prep stuff for context:

```
CREATE TABLE spenttime (userid int, serverid int, [time] int, [day] DATETIME)


CREATE TABLE weeklookup (weekname VARCHAR(10), weekstart DATETIME, weekend DATETIME)

INSERT INTO spenttime (userid, serverid, [time], [day]) VALUES
    (1, 1, 200, '2013-apr-01'),
    (1, 1, 150, '2013-apr-02'),
    (2, 1, 100, '2013-apr-02'),
    (3, 1, 500, '2013-apr-04'),
    (2, 2, 400, '2013-apr-04'),
    (1, 1, 300, '2013-apr-08'),
    (3, 1, 200, '2013-apr-08');

INSERT INTO weeklookup(weekname, weekstart, weekend) VALUES
     ('2013-w14', '01/apr/2013', '08/apr/2013'),
     ('2013-w15', '08/apr/2013', '15/apr/2013')


GO 
CREATE VIEW weekgroup AS 

SELECT    a.userid ,
                    a.serverid ,
                    a.[time] ,
                    w1.weekname
          FROM      spenttime a
                    INNER JOIN weeklookup w1 ON [day] >= w1.weekstart
                                                 AND [day] < w1.weekend
GO
```

Select statement for the view:

```
SELECT  wv1.userid ,
        wv1.serverid ,
        wv1.[time] ,
        wv1.weekname AS yearweek ,
        COUNT(wv2.[time]) + 1 AS rank
FROM    weekgroup wv1
        LEFT JOIN weekgroup wv2 ON wv1.[time] < wv2.[time]
               AND wv1.weekname = wv2.weekname
               AND wv1.serverid = wv2.serverid
GROUP BY wv1.userid ,
        wv1.serverid ,
        wv1.[time] ,
        wv1.weekname
ORDER BY wv1.weekname ,
        wv1.[time] DESC
```

Comment: It's not working properly: first of all, it's ignoring serverid and computing ranking globaly, not by server. Secondly: it's not grouping time by player, week and server, so for each player there can be more entries in week. And last thing: i can't create view from that query (view can't have nested selects inside FROM in MySQL). I'm limited by ORM inside application and can't bypass it, so it must be computed inside view.

Comment: Ok well wasn't aware of that MySQL limitation. the subqueries are just getting the weekstart details. Off the top of my head I can't think of a way to group into week without a subquery & don't have time to give to it at the moment. Presumably you can work out how to get that without the subquery? As for the server_id - I missed that in your requirements, but it's pretty obvious how to do that if you follow how my query works - you just link cte1.serverid = cte2.serverid. Changed that in the above. Solve those two things and you're there.

Comment: edited above to show how simple the change needs to be - just pack the subqueries into a view and add the missed serverid criteria. Otherwise identical.

Comment: Now that answer is almost complete, there is only missing part about summing up all time in week spent on server by particular user. But it is easy to fix just by adding group by and sum into weekgroup view. Also, table weeklookup isn't needed because there is function called yearweek in MySQL but removing that and fixing sum of time will make this answer almost identical to answer posted by fthiella

Comment: I guess my point was that you said you were having a problem getting the rank - which is what I addressed - the other stuff is peripheral and very easy to solve. I agree other answer is more or less identical - once you have the principle I demonstrated in my post there are only so many ways to proceed. Not contesting the answer status tho.

Comment: My problem was specifically to create rank column inside view. If I can do it with totally custom select, it is pretty easy to solve but views have some limitations and I had no idea how to overcome it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the rank, you would use an `insert` trigger.  The insert trigger would calculate the rank, as something like:

```
select count(*)
from spenttime_week w
where w.yearweek = new.yearweek and time >= new.time
```

However, I would not recommend this, because you then have to create an `update` trigger as well, and modify rank values that are already inserted.

Instead, access the table using SQL like:

```
select w.*,
       (select count(*) from spenttime_week w2 where w2.yearweek = w.yearweek and w2.time >= w.time
       ) as rank
from spenttime_week w
```

This SQL may vary, depending on how you want to handle ties in the data.  For performance reasons, you should have an index on at least `yearweek`, and probably on `yearweek, time`.

Comment: Sorry, but `spenttime_week` is an **viev**, not an table, so triggers are not an option. Also the column rank must exist on that Viev, because I can't calculate additional columns in app that I will use it... But thanks for try :)

Comment: @GwynBleidD . . . So edit the view and add the additional column suggested.  Be sure the underlying tables have the right indexes, and performance should be ok.

Comment: But adding that column is actually the pain in my head... I don't know how to do it...